# Multiplication operator on Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

i looked to the question [Spectrum and point spectrum of this operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237284/spectrum-and-point-spectrum-of-this-operator). I will go further with asking. We know that $T$ is well-defined iff $(\lambda_n)\in\ell^{\infty}$. But if $(\lambda_n)\notin\ell^{\infty}$ then we can defined this operator also on a new domain $D(T)$ given by $D(T)=\{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x_ne_n}\in\ell^2: \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{|\lambda_nx_n|^2}<\infty\}$. My first question is: Is this $D(T)$ dense in $\ell^2$?

I observe that $T$ is well-defined on $D(T)$. Thus we can also ask about the spectrum of $T$. We have seen in [Spectrum and point spectrum of this operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237284/spectrum-and-point-spectrum-of-this-operator) that the spectrum is $\sigma(T)=\overline{\{\lambda_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}}$. Can we say this also for $T$ defined on $D(T)$? Is it the same argumentation?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $D(T)$ is dense in $\ell^2$, since it contains all finite linear combinations of the $e_n$, which are dense in $\ell^2$ since $\{e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $\ell^2$.

Let us turn to $\sigma(T)$. It is still the case that $T e_n = \lambda_n e_n$ for each $n$, so each $\lambda_n$ is an honest-to-goodness eigenvalue of $T$, and hence, $\overline{\{\lambda_n\}} \subseteq \sigma(T)$. On the other hand, observe that for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{\lambda_n\}$,
$$
 (T - \lambda \operatorname{Id})\left(\sum_n x_n e_n \right) = \sum_n (\lambda_n - \lambda)x_n e_n,
$$
so that $T - \lambda \operatorname{Id}$ is invertible at least on the dense subspace of finite linear combinations of the $e_n$, with inverse
$$
 (T - \lambda \operatorname{Id})^{-1}\left(\sum_n x_n e_n \right) = \sum_n (\lambda_n - \lambda)^{-1}x_n e_n.
$$
Hence, by the result you cite, $(T - \lambda \operatorname{Id})^{-1}$ extends to a bounded operator on $\ell^2$ if and only if
$$
 \left( (\lambda_n - \lambda)^{-1} \right) \in \ell^\infty,
$$
if and only if there exists some $0 < K < +\infty$ such that
$$
 |\lambda_n - \lambda|^{-1} \leq K
$$
which holds, in turn, if and only if there exists some $0 < K < +\infty$ such that
$$
 |\lambda_n - \lambda| \geq K^{-1},
$$
which is equivalent, if I'm not mistaken, to $\lambda \notin \overline{\{\lambda_n\}}$. Hence, one should still have that
$$
 \sigma(T) = \overline{\{\lambda_n\}}.
$$

Comment: Thanky you very much. Do must have to pay attention to the $D(T-\lambda I)$ and $D((T-\lambda I)^{-1})$ because by definition we must have $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}(T-\lambda I)\subset(T-\lambda I)(T-\lambda I)^{-1}=I$

Comment: Can we with this information also make a statement over $T^*$?

Comment: Even though $T$ isn't necessarily bounded, it is diagonalised by the orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$, so that $T$, $T^\ast$, and any sensible function of $T$ and/or $T^\ast$ will be well-defined at least on the dense subspace $S$ of finite linear combinations of the $e_n$, and will, in particular, also be diagonalised by $\{e_n\}$. For example, by considering $\langle \xi, T \eta\rangle$ for $\eta \in D(T)$ and $\xi \in S$, one sees that $T^\ast$ is defined by $\sum_n x_n e_n \mapsto  \sum_n \overline{\lambda_n} x_n e_n$ at least on $S$, and hence that $D(T^\ast) = D(T)$.